# Excel Basic: Multiple conditions and cases with different output

Tags: excel

I have two numbers A1 and B1, and on C1 I want to do the following.

If the number in  A1 satisfies a < A1 <= b AND c <= B1 < d, then I want C1 to show success.
If a < A1 <= b is satisfied but not c <= B1 < d, I want C1 to show TOO LOW.
And similarly if c <= B1 < d is satisfied but a < A1 <= b is not, I want C1 to show TOO HIGH.

I initially wanted to use the IF function but I was not quite sure how to split them into cases and I'm sure there is a way.  I'm just not too familiar with Excel words and did not know what I am trying to do is called so I could not look for it on my own...

It would be of great help.

Comment: What is supposed to happen if neither of the conditions are satisfied? You have specified outcomes for 3 out of 4 Boolean combinations

Comment: Take a look at this [http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/excel-if-statement/]. You can nest If statements inside each other too.

Comment: @John Coleman Ah, did not think of that.  The condition I was going to put particularly will force at least one or both of the condition to be satisfied so I did not think of that.

Comment: It never hurts to provide code for a logically possible case, even if you judge the case to be an error condition.

Comment: @ dev 1998 I'm sorry but the link you pasted does not seem to go anywhere.

Comment: That's weird. This one might work: [https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69AED7C9-4E8A-4755-A9BC-AA8BBFF73BE2]

Comment: Okay, John this is what I have tried.  

IFERROR(IF(1<=[@[Forecast Variance - 5%]]<=21/19 AND(19/21<[@[Forecast Variance + 5%]]<1),"Success",IF(1>[@[Forecast Variance - 5%]],"Too Low",IF( [@[Forecast Variance + 5%]]>1,"Too High", "N/A")

Comment: @ dev1988  I took a look at it and it actually was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: `AND` is not an infix operator. `P AND Q` isn't a valid Excel Formula (though it would be valid VBA). Instead, you need `AND(P,Q)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested if statements along with `And` is the way to go. Something like:

```
=IF(AND(1<A1,A1<5),IF(AND(4<=B1,B1<10),"Success","Too Low"),IF(AND(4<=B1,B1<10),"Too High","Failure"))
```

I arbitrarily picked a = 1, b = 5, c = 4, d = 10 in your problem description and decided that the cases where both conditions fail should be called, well, "Failure"

The logic is as follows, first the condition on `A1` is tested. If it is satisfied then the condition on `B1` is tested. If it is also satisfied, then `"Success"` is returned, otherwise `"Too Low"`. At this stage we have taken care of what to do if the condition on `A1` is satisfied. If it isn't -- we move on to the `Else` part of the outer if statement (the second half of the overall formula. We again check `B1`. If it is true and we reach this part of the formula, we know that we should return `"Too High"`, on the other hand, if `B1` still fails the condition and `A1` fails it as well, the formula reports a failure.

Comment: Quick question.  Can I not use 1<A1<5 instead of 1<A1,A1<5 ?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for your help anyways.  I'm studying these things on my own since I am trying to change my career and hopefully I can learn a lot more once I get a job.